# Android RecyclerView lags when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have the following code in my recycler adapter. When scrolling down, recycler starts to lag while glide loads asynchronous images. If I remove glide then is all perfect. Any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Customer customer= customerList.get(position);

   ((CustomerViewHolder)holder).binding.setCustomer (customer);

   RequestOptions ro = new RequestOptions();

    ro.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE);
    ro.skipMemoryCache(true);
    ro.centerCrop();

            Glide.with(mCtx)
                    .applyDefaultRequestOptions(ro)
                    .load(customer.getImagePath())
                    .into(((CustomerViewHolder)holder).binding.imageView);

        ((CustomerViewHolder)holder).binding.executePendingBindings();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set a fixed height for your ViewHolder prior to loading the image. If the ViewHolder is resized as it's binding, it will cause the scroll to stutter.